# how to set DTL(Django Tamplate language) for loop and value through javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to set django for loop to set value through javascript like this. is this correct way? or Is there any other way?

```
    var table = $('.checkbox-datatable').DataTable({
        'scrollCollapse': true,
        'autoWidth': false,
        'responsive': true,
        "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
        "language": {
            "info": "_START_-_END of TOTAL_ entries",
            searchPlaceholder: "Search",
            paginate: {
                next: '<i class="ion-chevron-right"></i>',
                previous: '<i class="ion-chevron-left"></i>'  
            }
        },
        'columnDefs': [{
            'targets': 0,
            'searchable': false,
            'orderable': false,
            'className': 'dt-body-center',
            'render': function (data, type, full, meta){
                return '<div class="dt-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name=

"id[]" id="chkuser"  value="' +  {% for dd in departmentData %}{{dd.id}}{% endfor %} + '" /><span class="dt-checkbox-label"></span></div>';
        }
    }],
    'order': [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

Comment: This will not work, you need to `declare variables`  for javascript `outside of this script` in your `.html page`, and then you can `for loop` in this script with `javascript`

Comment: You can use an AJAX call. All you have to do is return JsonResponse and write an AJAX function for GET method so you can have the data on JS.

Comment: but this code is into the .js file, so first how {{dd.id}} will work in any .js file and also it is still showing me an error after putting any DTL... ????https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lwvesPx4cYbPgXZXOwPLwz2djGXWMjHD/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @CaptionAmerica I have updated the answer so you can see the logic of it.

Answer (score 1):

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('get_department_data/', views.get_department_data, name = "get_department_data")
    # ...

]
```

views:

```
def get_department_data(request):
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "GET":
        q = YourModel.objects.all().values()
        data = []
        for i in q:
            data.append([(i['field1'],i['field2'])])
        return JsonResponse({"data":data}, status = 200)
```

HTML:

```
<input value="{% url 'get_department_data' %}" type="hidden"></input>
```

js:

```
dd_url = $('#department_data_url').val();
$.ajax({
    url: dd_url,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response.data); 
        $.each(response.data, function (i, obj) {
              console.log( obj[0][0] , obj[0][1] ); 
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: your code is not working with my requirements but i got solution from https://github.com/dropways/deskapp/issues/47
But thanks for sharing your code because it cleared some of my concepts.